Setting up Linux Mail Server with SpamAssassin: How to Receive Emails and Retrieve Spam Scores Programmatically?
I'm looking to set up a mail server on Linux that can receive emails, analyze them using SpamAssassin, and then return the spam score results. My goal is to integrate this into an application where I can check the spam score before sending out email blasts.
Could anyone provide guidance or a step-by-step approach on how to achieve this? Specifically:
How do I set up a mail server on Linux to receive incoming emails? How can I configure SpamAssassin to analyze these incoming emails for spam detection? Once SpamAssassin has analyzed an email, how do I retrieve the spam score programmatically? Are there any best practices or considerations I should keep in mind for integrating this spam score check into an application? Any insights, examples, or recommended resources would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

"My goal is to integrate this into an application where I can check the spam score before sending out email blasts" - why not call SpamAssassin directly with your intended email message? So much easier
